# Next.js Error if .woff2 files in public folder

Tags: webpack, next.js

I have put a bunch of .woff2 - files in my public folder (public/static/fonts) and even without referencing these in my code anywhere, the compiler throws:

```
error - ./public/static/fonts/JetBrainsMono-Bold.woff2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I really would like to know whats happening here, and why the compiler searchs my public folder at all. Optimizations probably?

Probably i need to install a loader, but i´d rather have a solution where nextjs doesn´t search my public folder.

Comment: Which version of next.js are you using? Actually, next.js automatically loads everything inside the public folder as static files. Maybe just delete .next folder and try to restart the server.